# How to fix border radius on ios with react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

border radius is not working as it should in react native on ios

this is the code and the result i am getting on ios below

```
<View style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }} >
  <Image source={{ uri: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667.jpg' }} 
          style={{ height: 150, width: 150, borderRadius: 100 }} />
</View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a border-radius with 50% if the with height/hight whenever you want to obtain a circle.

In your case it would be 75